# CustomTextField doesn't work when added in Fxml

Tags: java, javafx

I have `TextField` with cross to clear input. When I'm adding it like this:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private TextField autoCompleteTextField = TextFields.createClearableTextField();
    ...
```

and then:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources){

    autoComplete1 = TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(autoCompleteTextField,callback, converter);
    autoCompletePane.getChildren().add(autoCompleteTextField);
```

Everything works great. But when i want to add this item in SceneBuilder or manualy in Fxml:

```
<Pane fx:id="autoCompletePane" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="444.0">
    <children>
        <CustomTextField fx:id="autoCompleteTextField" layoutX="25.0" layoutY="3.0" />  
        // or TextField instead of CustomTextField
    </children>
</Pane>
```

normal `TextField` is inserted, without cross to clear input.
What can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a `static` method not taking parameters to create the textfield using [the `fx:factory` attribute](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#instance_declaration_elements):

```xml
<Pane fx:id="autoCompletePane" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="444.0">
    <children>
        <TextFields fx:id="autoCompleteTextField" fx:factory="createClearableTextField" layoutX="25.0" layoutY="3.0" />
    </children>
</Pane>
```

(This requires an import processing instruction for the `TextFields` class of course.)